# ImportError when using django-address

Tags: django, google-maps

I am using [`django-address`](https://github.com/furious-luke/django-address) in a Django 1.7 project and I get an `ImportError` whenever I try to create an object containing at least one `AddressField`.

The traceback says

```
cannot import name GoogleMapsError
```

The exception is thrown by this particular import statement:

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMapsError
```

I tried to manually install `googlemaps` from `pip` but it did not help because `GoogleMapsError` could not be found in the module. The instructions from `django-address` do not mention any explicit dependency so I'm a bit confused.

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like django-address code was based on:
http://sourceforge.net/p/py-googlemaps/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/googlemaps/googlemaps.py

(which it seems you'd get by `pip install googlemaps==1.0.2` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlemaps/1.0.2)

However there is a newer version of googlemaps https://pypi.python.org/pypi/googlemaps/2.0 which is what you'd get if you just `pip install googlemaps` now... and this has different code:
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python

So, I believe that `pip install googlemaps==1.0.2` should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually that reference to `GoogleMapsError` is from an older version of `django-address` and is now unused. I've removed it from the code and, consequently, the dependence on `py-googlemaps`. Please try reinstalling the latest version of `django-address` from the Github repository. Thanks!